# how to restart matlab local scheduler in a clean state?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, memory-leaks, parallel-processing, job-scheduling

I have 9 parallel jobs using matlab local scheduler configuration of parallel toolbox which will be triggered at scheduled times.

I want the deployed application to run continuously but the problem is when a job is finished, although I destroy the jobs on the worker side and also clear the job objects on the client side, it remains in the client. Therefore, after hours of continuous running, the deployed application will crash.

one possibility is to restart the job manager after a certain time, but there is still a problem with using the local scheduler profile. for example if I try to start the workers in clean state by setting "RestartWorker" property to true, I will get this error:

> The name 'RestartWorker' is not an accessible property for an instance
>   of class 'simpleparalleljob'.

I prefer not to setup a cluster and buy a commercial scheduler like MATLAB Distributed Computing Server (MDCS).

I was wondering if anybody has a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not really the same question, but perhaps a setup where you start a program for a short task and then close it can do the trick? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204663/run-a-script-that-uses-multiple-matlab-sessions