# how to delete variables in matlab command window?

Tags: matlab

I want to delete some variables that I have declared in command window in matlab, I tried clear all but it didn't work. I typed the following in the command window,
e.g.

```
a = 10;
str = 'a';
clear all
```

Matlab doesn't delete them, why?
Is there any function that can do this for me?

Comment: `clear all` certainly deletes variables from the workspace (unless you've managed to redefine `clear`).  Do you mean you want to empty the command window ?  If so, try `clc`.

Comment: If you have managed to redefine clear, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360624/how-to-remove-the-variable-clear-in-matlab for how to clear `clear`

Answer (score 1):

1)
If you have redefined function *clear* (e.g. by a variable or function), you can use the [builtin](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) function to execute built-in *clear* function.
I.e. you can use

```
builtin('clear','all')
```

to clear all variables,
respectively

```
builtin('clear','clear')
```

to redefine clear to the built-in *clear* function and then use it normally

```
clear all
```

2) If this was not the solution of your problem, could you show us the output of the following code?

```
a = 10;
str = 'a';
builtin('clear','all')
builtin('who')
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear all of your variables in matlab you type:

```
clear
```

If you want to clear a specific variable, for instance "a" you tpye:

```
clear a
```

I suspect your problem is that you have named a variable "all" so when you use `clear all` you end up only clearing the variable all.

You should be careful about what names you are giving to your variables. You can use`exist {variable}` to check if the variable you want to assign is already used by a matlab function.

Answer (score 1):

use "**Clear**" only  it will work or u want to remove particular variable the put variable name in last of " **Clear Var_name**"