# How to store variable length arrays?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, variable-length-array

I want to store an array which changes its size in each iteration of a for loop.
For example,

```
for y=1:100
    for x=1:50
.
.
        ms(:,x,y) = ans;
.
.
    end 
end
```

The 'ans' is a row vector which changes its size in each iteration of y.

How can i store these variable length 'ans' into ms?

When i try to initialize 'ms' as cell, it shows an error saying "Conversion to cell from double is not possible."

What are the ways i can solve this?

Thanks 
Kind regards

Comment: Use cell arrays, i.e. `{}` instead of `()`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
ms = {};
for y=1:100
    for x=1:50
       ms = [ms 1:x];
       % or
       % ms = [ms new_cell_element];
    end 
end
```

You can also index the cell array with `ms{x,y} = 1:3;` 
`new_cell_element` does *not* need to be a cell, it can be anything you want.

```
ms = [ms, 'A string', (1:5).'] %// Works!
```

Note that I do not recommend this, and I'm pretty sure there are other ways to do this, depending on what you want to do inside those nested loops. You should check out [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and read up on [`cells`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) in general.

Also, *never ever* use `ans` as a variable name in MATLAB. That will only cause you trouble. Any other name is better [(except `clear` and `builtin`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360624/how-to-remove-the-variable-clear-in-matlab).

Comment: ahahahaa, about 30 seconds off of each other.  That's funny :)

Comment: Hah! You were _waaay_ to slow @rayryeng! I would give you a +1, but seeing as you have `ans` as the variable name still, I just can't do it =P

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to indeed use a cell array.  Initialize a 2D cell array like so:

```
ms = cell(50,100);
```

After, you index into the cell by using curly braces (`{}`).  Therefore, your loop will look like:

```
for y=1:100
    for x=1:50
.
.
        ms{x,y} = ans;
.
.
    end 
end
```

After you're done, you can index into the cell array by choosing the row and column location you want:

```
vec = ms{row,col};
```

BTW, I don't recommend you use `ans` as a variable.  `ans` is the default variable that is used when you execute a statement in MATLAB which has an output and you don't specify a variable of where this output from the function will go.  You may have code that will overwrite the `ans` variable, so you should perhaps use another name.