# How can I write-protect the Matlab language?

Tags: matlab, function, syntax

Matlab allows you to overwrite built in functions without so much as a warning.

For example, I've overwritten the function `max()` with a variable, but Matlab doesn't alert me to this.  An error is only thrown later when the function is called, and doesn't help you see the actual problem:

```
min     = 0;
max     = 10;
x       = linspace(min,max,20);
y       = exp(x);
disp(['the value is: ', num2str(max(y))])
```

Error message:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

**Is there a way to write-protect all of the Matlab language at startup, or in a settings file to prevent this?**

Comment: Interesting question. What do you want if you type `max = 3`? An error, nothing, a warning ... ? You can always ensure you run the builtin function by using `builtin`, like this `x = builtin('max',[-4, 3])`, but that's of course very cumbersome. _Make sure to not [overload `builtin`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18360748/2338750)!!_

Comment: Well... an error/warning when I overwrite would be nice.  So would a notice in the interactive editor.  Nice to know the `builtin` functionality, but I'd probably just change my variable name.

Comment: I guess this is not possible. Maybe only when overloading **every** single fundamental class in Matlab http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html But I don't recommend it. It can make Matlab useless when you're doing it wrong. But you can always checkt with `>> exist possible_var_name` if it already exist. `>> which something_that_exist` tells you where it is from or what it is.

Comment: +1 for exist.  While these tools could help avoid the issue (I usually do `help possible_var_name` if I'm unsure) it kind of bothers me that the functions aren't write protected!  This is as much an issue when I'm doing extensive work between a script and the command window, and things get a bit complicated.

Comment: @StewieGriffin you could save a handle to `builtin` in time if you anticipate it being overwritten later;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 9/2015, I have not found a way to *easily* write protect native matlab functions/language, as a setting/flag/etc at startup.

If you are concerned about a particular function, there are various ways to see if they are shadowed, including Luis Mendo's answer: `which('name_of_function', '-all')`.

If a method is found in the future, I will gladly accept that answer!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know a way to do what you want. But there's a way to **check if a specific function has been shadowed**, either by a variable or by other function, using [`which`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html): namely, analyze the output of `which(fname, '-all')`, where `fname` is a string containing the function name.

Take the `max` function as an example: compare (no shadowing)

```
>> clear all
>> fname = 'max';
>> which(fname, '-all')
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@logical\max)  % logical method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@char\max)     % char method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@double\max)   % double method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint8\max)    % uint8 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint16\max)   % uint16 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint32\max)   % uint32 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint64\max)   % uint64 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int8\max)     % int8 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int16\max)    % int16 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int32\max)    % int32 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int64\max)    % int64 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@single\max)   % single method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries\max.m     % timeseries method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\max.m  % codistributed method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\shared\statslib\@ordinal\max.m          % ordinal method
```

with (shadowing)

```
>> fname = 'max';
>> max = 10;
>> which(fname, '-all')
max is a variable.
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@logical\max)  % Shadowed logical method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@char\max)     % Shadowed char method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@double\max)   % Shadowed double method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint8\max)    % Shadowed uint8 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint16\max)   % Shadowed uint16 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint32\max)   % Shadowed uint32 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint64\max)   % Shadowed uint64 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int8\max)     % Shadowed int8 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int16\max)    % Shadowed int16 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int32\max)    % Shadowed int32 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int64\max)    % Shadowed int64 method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@single\max)   % Shadowed single method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries\max.m     % Shadowed timeseries method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\max.m  % Shadowed codistributed method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\shared\statslib\@ordinal\max.m          % Shadowed ordinal method
```

In the second case, `which(fname, '-all')` tells you that `max` is a variable that is shadowing several methods.

So, to test if shadowing is taking place,

1. Assign the output of `which(fname, '-all')` to a variable.

   In principle this could be done as `s = which(fname, '-all');`. Unfortunately, however, this produces a different output; in particular, the `% ...` part in the lines above (which tells if there is shadowing) is removed:

   ```
   >> fname = 'max';
   >> s = which(fname, '-all')
   s = 
       'variable'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@logical\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@char\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@double\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint8\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint16\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint32\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint64\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int8\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int16\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int32\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int64\max)'
       'built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@single\max)'
       'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries\max.m'
       'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\max.m'
       'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\shared\statslib\@ordinal\max.m'
   ```

   So we need to resort to [`evalc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) to get the full output: `s = evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')');`. The result `s` is a long string containing all lines (including the `% ...` parts) separated by line feed characters:

   ```
   >> fname = 'max';
   >> s = evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')')
   s =
   max is a variable.
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@logical\max)  % Shadowed logical method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@char\max)     % Shadowed char method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@double\max)   % Shadowed double method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint8\max)    % Shadowed uint8 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint16\max)   % Shadowed uint16 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint32\max)   % Shadowed uint32 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@uint64\max)   % Shadowed uint64 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int8\max)     % Shadowed int8 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int16\max)    % Shadowed int16 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int32\max)    % Shadowed int32 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@int64\max)    % Shadowed int64 method
   built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\@single\max)   % Shadowed single method
   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries\max.m     % Shadowed timeseries method
   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\max.m  % Shadowed codistributed method
   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\shared\statslib\@ordinal\max.m          % Shadowed ordinal method
   ```
2. Analyze the string `s` obtained in step 1 to see if it contains `'% Shadowed'`. This is easily done with [`strfind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html): namely, `strfind(s, '% Shadowed')` will be non-empty if there is shadowing.

**In conclusion**:

Putting it all together,

```
isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'));
```

returns `true` if the function with name contained in variable `fname` is shadowed, and `false` otherwise.

**Example with a variable**:

```
>> clear all
>> fname = 'max';
>> max = 10;
>> isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'))
isShadowed =
     1
>> clear max
>> isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'))
isShadowed =
     0
```

**Example with a named function**:

Create a function in file `std.m` and place it in your path. This will shadow Matlab's `std` function.

```
>> fname = 'std';
>> isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'))
isShadowed =
     1
```

Now delete the function file (or remove its folder from the path):

```
>> fname = 'std';
>> isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'))
isShadowed =
     0
```

**Example with an anonymous function**:

```
>> std = @(x) x+1;
>> fname = 'std';
>> isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'))
isShadowed =
     1
>> clear std
>> isShadowed = ~isempty(strfind(evalc('which(fname, ''-all'')'), '% Shadowed'))
isShadowed =
     0
```

Comment: Thanks Luis.  This is good information, but its not exactly what I'm looking for :/.  I was hoping there was an elegant solution, say a '-nowrite` flag or preference I could change that would modify matlab's behavior.  This is helpful once a function is already overwritten.

Comment: Yes, I know. What you want would be interesting to achieve