# Simple parallel execution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have figured out some awesome ways of speeding up my MATLAB code: vectorizing, arrayfun, and basically just getting rid of for loops (not using parfor). I want to take it to the next step.

Suppose I have 2 function calls that are computationally intensive.

```
x = fun(a);
y = fun(b);
```

They are completely independent, and I want to run them in parallel rather than serially. I dont have the parallel processing toolbox. Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: `arrayfun` for speeding up? I don't think so. A `for` loop is usually faster. As for parallelizing, see `matlabpool` / `parpool`: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/distcomp/parpool.html

Comment: Note that the best speedups are usually not achieved by doing the calculations faster, but by (only) calculating the right things in the right way.

Comment: hopefully that clarified a little bit...

Comment: Luis, is that a little more clear? I'm pretty sure serial for loops are slower than using arrayfun (commonly known as map)...

Comment: I really dont understand why you guys are hating on this question so badly...

Comment: @Chet `arrafun` vs. `for`: See for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why

Comment: @LuisMendo There is actually a version of [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/arrayfun.html) in the Parallel Computing Toolbox, which utilizes GPUs to perform distributed computations, so it's probably wiser to understand if the question concerns it before dismissing it :)

Comment: @EitanT Oops, I didn't know about that version of `arrayfun`.

Answer (score 4):

If I am optimistic I think you ask "How Can I simply do parallel processing in Matlab". In that case the answer would be:

Parallel processing can most easily be done with the [parallel computing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/parallel-computing/). This gives you access to things like [`parfor`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/distcomp/parfor.html).

I guess you can do:

```
parfor t = 1:2
   if t == 1, x = fun(a); end
   if t == 2, y = fun(b); end
end
```

Of course there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204663/run-a-script-that-uses-multiple-matlab-sessions), but that should be the simplest.

Comment: I see -- I dont have the parallel processing toolbox though :(

Answer (score 4):

The MATLAB interpreter is single-threaded, so the only way to achieve parallelism across MATLAB functions is to run multiple instances of MATLAB. Parallel Computing Toolbox does this for you, and gives you a convenient interface in the form of PARFOR/SPMD/PARFEVAL etc. You can run multiple MATLAB instances manually, but you'll probably need to do a fair bit of work to organise the work that you want to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The usual examples involve [`parfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html), which is probably the easiest way to get parallelism out of MATLAB's Parallel Computing Toolbox (PCT).  The `parfeval` function is quite easy, as demonstrated in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19581502/2778484). A less frequently discussed functionality of the PCT is the system of `job`s and `task`s, which are probably the most appropriate solution for your simple case of two completely independent function calls.  Spoiler: the `batch` command can help to simplify creation of simple jobs (see bottom of this post).

Unfortunately, it is not as straightforward to implement; for the sake of completeness, here's an example:

```
% Build a cluster from the default profile
c = parcluster();

% Create an independent job object
j = createJob(c);

% Use cells to pass inputs to the tasks
taskdataA = {field1varA,...};
taskdataB = {field1varB,...};

% Create the task with 2 outputs
nTaskOutputs = 2;
t = createTask(j, @myCoarseFunction, nTaskOutputs, {taskdataA, taskdataB});

% Start the job and wait for it to finish the tasks
submit(j); wait(j);

% Get the ouptuts from each task
taskoutput = get(t,'OutputArguments');

delete(j); % do not forget to remove the job or your APPDATA folder will fill up!

% Get the outputs
out1A = taskoutput{1}{1};
out1B = taskoutput{2}{1};

out2A = taskoutput{1}{2};
out2B = taskoutput{2}{2};
```

The key here is the function `myCoarseFunction` given to [`createTask`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/createtask.html) as the function to evaluate in the task objects to creates.  This can be your `fun` or a wrapper if you have complicated inputs/outputs that might require a struct container.

Note that for a single task, the entire workflow above of creating a job and task, then starting them with `submit` can be **simplified with `batch`** as follows:

```
c = parcluster();
jobA = batch(c, @myCoarseFunction, 1, taskdataA,...
    'Pool', c.NumWorkers / 2 - 1, 'CaptureDiary', true);
```

Also, keep in mind that as with `matlabpool`(now called `parpool`), using `parcluster` requires time to startup the MATLAB.exe processes that will run your job.

Comment: I'm getting an warning of `myCoarseFunction` doesn't exists.

Comment: @AhsanAli This is an example.  Say you have some function called `myCoarseFunction`, this is how you'd do it.

Comment: please tell how to apply this on my code: `    parfor ii = 1:1000
    p{ii,1}=  repmat([2 4 5;],500,1); %suppose very big matrix
    pp{ii,1}=p{ii,1}*2;
    for jj = 1:100
    p1{jj,1} = p{ii}* pp{ii};
    p2{jj} = p{ii}* pp{ii}*p1{jj};
    p3{jj} = p{ii}* pp{ii}*p1{jj}*p2{ii};
    end
Data(ii).data=([pp(ii,:),p1{:,1},p2,p3;])' ;
Data(ii).label=cellfun(@(x) ['label' num2str(ii)] , num2cell(1:length(pp)+length(p1)+length(p2)+length(p3))', 'UniformOutput', false);
    end`